# Pinched Subsurf on Extruded Edges

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm trying to make some rounded edges and using the subsurf modifier to round 'em off. The problem is because the corner sits on an edge, there's some pinching. I'm really starting to understand the "quirks" of the subsurf modifier but having toyed with this part for quite a while, I'm not sure of which edges to crease/uncrease, or more likely, where I would need to add/remove/change geometry.
[image]
I'm looking to have that corner in the center be rounded, not pinched towards the edge at the bottom. Another problem I'm having which may be related is below: one side is flat, but the other side is again pinched, this time towards the center
[image]
The same part on the other side without subsurf:
[image]

Here is what the ideal result would be; as can be seen, the circle has no pinched edges.
[image]
Thing is though, above is the result of the three highlighted faces being extruded out and moved back in line with the edge. So there is overlapping edges/vertices, which isn't pleasant. Here is what happens if the verts merge together:
[image]

Comment: Rather than using edge crease, you should try to fix your problem with the topology itself. Maybe show one shape that you are trying to achieve so that we can propose a solution.

Comment: @moonboots Definitely a question of topology, I don't expect the edge creases to do much. I've updated the question with the desired outcome

Comment: so is the cylinder supposed to stick to the vertical wall ? https://zupimages.net/up/21/05/lsmp.jpg ... or is it what you want? https://zupimages.net/up/21/05/u5bk.jpg

Comment: It'd be the latter image, with the cylinder rounded

Comment: so what about the topology I show? You just need to cut a hole in your cube, extrude and scale the extrusion inwards, make a circle with Alt Shift S, extrude up; add edge loops to sharp the edges...

Comment: I imagine that's just like an inset then extrude? It seems to be a viable workaround. Thanks.

Comment: yes make sure you have enough edge loops, delete the central vertex to cut a hole, extrude inwards and make a circle with LoopTools > Circle, then extrude up, and add edge loops to sharp the edges